# Show that extension $\mathbb{R}(x) \supseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a real extension (ordered extension)

Tags: ordered-fields, real-algebraic-geometry

> **Problem:** Denote $\mathbb{R}(x)$ be the quotient field of polynomial ring in single variable $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Show that extension $\mathbb{R}(x) \supseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a real extension (ordered extension).

**My attempt:** Follows the definition of real extension, if we denote ordering on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is $\le_{\mathbb{R}(x)}$ then $\mathbb{R}(x) \supseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a real extension iff the restriction of $\le_{\mathbb{R}(x)}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x), f'(x), g(x), g'(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le_{\mathbb{R}(x)} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Let $g(x) = 1, \forall x$ then we have $f(x) \le f'(x)$. Q.E.D

Comment: You haven't stated what $\le_{\mathbb R(x)}$ is. Since $\mathbb R(x)$ isn't real closed, it has more than one possible ordering. Also, how does $f(x) \le f'(x)$ prove that $\le_{\mathbb R(x)}$ restricted to $\mathbb R$ is the ordering on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are two distinct polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $g'(x)$ is not the derivative of $g(x)$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I used the definition of real extension (ordered extension) to do this proof.

Comment: You've shown that an ordering on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ restricts to an ordering on $\mathbb{R}[x]$. But you haven't shown that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ admits an ordering or that its ordering is compatible with the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: To say that $\mathbb R(x)$ is a real extension of $\mathbb R$ means that **THERE EXISTS** an ordering $\le_{\mathbb R(x)}$ satisfying some properties. To show something exists, you have to first define it, give a formula for it, say what it is. Then you check that it satisfies the properties. You haven't done those things yet.

Comment: @LeeMosher Could I define an ordering on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Answer (score 1):

So I don't believe there is a common enough ordering on $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to be called the "usual" one. For real-closed fields, such as $\mathbb{R}$ the ordering is uniquely defined by $a > 0$ if $a = b^2$ for some $b$.

For $\mathbb{R}(x)$ since $x$ is not a square or a sum of squares, there's nothing to say whether we should have $x > 0$ or $x < 0$. In fact, given any ordering of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ we can swap $x$ and $-x$ an get a different ordering in which the sign of $x$ is swapped.

I would say the easiest way to see that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is formally-real isn't via any order but to see that $-1$ isn't a sum of squares. For suppose

$$ -1 = \sum \left(\frac{f_i(x)}{g_i(x)}\right)^2 $$

and pick $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $g_i(a) \ne 0$ for any $i$. Then

$$ -1 = \sum \left(\frac{f_i(a)}{g_i(a)}\right)^2, $$

which is impossible.

[Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Examples_of_ordered_fields) an ordering on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ where the positive cone is

$$\left\{\frac fg : \frac{\text{leading coefficient of }f}{\text{leading coefficient of }g} > 0 \right\}.$$

But like I said, this ordering isn't unique. One then has to check that this ordering makes $\mathbb{R}(x)$ into an ordered field. This ordering obviously extends the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$.

Although, you don't really need to think about whether the ordering extends that of $\mathbb{R}$. No matter what ordering you have, sums of squares are always positive and in $\mathbb{R}$, the positive cone is exactly the set of squares. Thus any ordering on some field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ will always extend the order on $\mathbb{R}$.